# Why is the Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OwinSelfHost nuget package empty?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, nuget, owin, self-hosting

The Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OwinSelfHost nuget package doesn't appear to contain anything.

Does it exist merely to group dependencies?

Is this good/bad practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that looks like a "meta" package. One that exists to group dependencies. This is very common. It makes it easier for the consumer, but allows the package maintainer to create granular packages.

You might also see an "empty" package when the maintainer has renamed a package. The old package will simply reference the new name. This way other packages that depend on the old one won't break.